# HTML code for Angular material table of contents

Tags: html, angular, tableofcontents

I am in the process of creating a long HTML page. I was interested in adding a table of contents just like in angular material however I cannot find any documentation on it anywhere. 
This is type of table of contents I'm looking for:

[Angular Table of Contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cT1Zc.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oflKg.jpg)

I have seen some npm alternatives but I'm not interested in those.

The code for the angular table of contents is as follows:

```
<table-of-contents container=".mat-drawer-content" _nghost-lwx-c20="" class="ng-star-inserted">
          <!---->
          <div _ngcontent-lwx-c20="" class="docs-toc-container ng-star-inserted">
            <div _ngcontent-lwx-c20="" class="docs-toc-heading">Contents</div>
            <nav _ngcontent-lwx-c20="">
              <!----><a _ngcontent-lwx-c20="" href="/components/datepicker/overview#connecting-a-datepicker-to-an-input"
                class="docs-level-h3 docs-link ng-star-inserted"> Connecting a datepicker to an input </a><a
                _ngcontent-lwx-c20="" href="/components/datepicker/overview#setting-the-calendar-starting-view"
                class="docs-level-h3 docs-link ng-star-inserted"> Setting the calendar starting view </a><a
                _ngcontent-lwx-c20=""
                href="/components/datepicker/overview#watching-the-views-for-changes-on-selected-years-and-months"
                class="docs-level-h4 docs-link ng-star-inserted"> Watching the views for changes on selected years and
                months </a><a _ngcontent-lwx-c20="" href="/components/datepicker/overview#setting-the-selected-date"
                class="docs-level-h3 docs-link ng-star-inserted"> Setting the selected date </a><a _ngcontent-lwx-c20=""
                href="/components/datepicker/overview#changing-the-datepicker-colors"
                class="docs-level-h3 docs-link ng-star-inserted"> Changing the datepicker colors </a><a
                _ngcontent-lwx-c20="" href="/components/datepicker/overview#date-validation"
                class="docs-level-h3 docs-link ng-star-inserted"> Date validation </a><a _ngcontent-lwx-c20=""
                href="/components/datepicker/overview#input-and-change-events"
                class="docs-level-h3 docs-link ng-star-inserted"> Input and change events </a><a _ngcontent-lwx-c20=""
                href="/components/datepicker/overview#disabling-parts-of-the-datepicker"
                class="docs-level-h3 docs-link ng-star-inserted"> Disabling parts of the datepicker </a><a
                _ngcontent-lwx-c20="" href="/components/datepicker/overview#touch-ui-mode"
                class="docs-level-h3 docs-link ng-star-inserted"> Touch UI mode </a><a _ngcontent-lwx-c20=""
                href="/components/datepicker/overview#manually-opening-and-closing-the-calendar"
                class="docs-level-h3 docs-link ng-star-inserted"> Manually opening and closing the calendar </a><a
                _ngcontent-lwx-c20="" href="/components/datepicker/overview#internationalization"
                class="docs-level-h3 docs-link ng-star-inserted"> Internationalization </a><a _ngcontent-lwx-c20=""
                href="/components/datepicker/overview#setting-the-locale-code"
                class="docs-level-h4 docs-link ng-star-inserted"> Setting the locale code </a><a _ngcontent-lwx-c20=""
                href="/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings"
                class="docs-level-h4 docs-link ng-star-inserted"> Choosing a date implementation and date format
                settings </a><a _ngcontent-lwx-c20=""
                href="/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-parse-and-display-formats"
                class="docs-level-h4 docs-link ng-star-inserted"> Customizing the parse and display formats </a><a
                _ngcontent-lwx-c20="" href="/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-calendar-header"
                class="docs-level-h4 docs-link ng-star-inserted"> Customizing the calendar header </a><a
                _ngcontent-lwx-c20="" href="/components/datepicker/overview#localizing-labels-and-messages"
                class="docs-level-h4 docs-link ng-star-inserted"> Localizing labels and messages </a><a
                _ngcontent-lwx-c20="" href="/components/datepicker/overview#highlighting-specific-dates"
                class="docs-level-h4 docs-link ng-star-inserted"> Highlighting specific dates </a><a
                _ngcontent-lwx-c20="" href="/components/datepicker/overview#accessibility"
                class="docs-level-h3 docs-link ng-star-inserted"> Accessibility </a><a _ngcontent-lwx-c20=""
                href="/components/datepicker/overview#keyboard-interaction"
                class="docs-level-h4 docs-link ng-star-inserted"> Keyboard interaction </a><a _ngcontent-lwx-c20=""
                href="/components/datepicker/overview#troubleshooting" class="docs-level-h3 docs-link ng-star-inserted">
                Troubleshooting </a><a _ngcontent-lwx-c20=""
                href="/components/datepicker/overview#error-matdatepicker-no-provider-found-for-dateadapter-mat_date_formats"
                class="docs-level-h4 docs-link ng-star-inserted"> Error: MatDatepicker: No provider found for
                DateAdapter/MAT_DATE_FORMATS </a><a _ngcontent-lwx-c20=""
                href="/components/datepicker/overview#error-a-matdatepicker-can-only-be-associated-with-a-single-input"
                class="docs-level-h4 docs-link ng-star-inserted"> Error: A MatDatepicker can only be associated with a
                single input </a><a _ngcontent-lwx-c20=""
                href="/components/datepicker/overview#error-attempted-to-open-an-matdatepicker-with-no-associated-input-"
                class="docs-level-h4 docs-link ng-star-inserted"> Error: Attempted to open an MatDatepicker with no
                associated input. </a></nav>
          </div>
        </table-of-contents>
```

When I try to run this code, the console prints `<table-of-contents>` is not a known element

Comment: The code above is from this page: 
https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview#simple-lists

Comment: This html code looks like its post-compilation... Did you just rip it out of inspect element?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes...
I was just hoping to use the <table-of-contents> but it seems the tag/component they are using is not available for public use

Comment: Ah, well also unfortunately, the angular material docs are written using the web framework Angular, so there's lots of javascript DOM interactions going on under the hood that can't be predicted. If you are using Angular to build your website, you can use their [Side Nav](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview), and use Angular routing to switch between html components. If you're not using Angular (which I suspect to be the case here), you're not going to have success copy pasting source code from their page.

Comment: I am using angular v8 at the moment for the website I'm building but I feel I will just have to create a perpetually open sidenav on the right side of the website which will serve as host for the table of contents. I think I have to make it myself I guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So for those who are running into a similar situation, I'm posting the solution below which was to create the component yourself. I inspected angular material and rebuilt it.

Here is the HTML code you will need:

```html
<div class="tableOfContentContainer">
  <div class="tableOfContent docs-toc-container">
    <div class="docs-toc-heading">Contents</div>
    <nav>
      <a href="/components/list/overview#simple-lists" class="docs-level-h3 docs-link ng-star-inserted">Simple lists</a>
      <br>
      <a href="/components/list/overview#navigation-lists" class="docs-level-h3 docs-link ng-star-inserted">Navigation lists</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the associated CSS:

```
.tableOfContentContainer{
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-left: 2em;
    position: fixed;
}
.docs-toc-container {
    border-left: 4px solid #3f51b5;
    font-weight: 700;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #737373;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
}
a:hover{
    color: #3f51b5;
}
.tableOfContent{
    padding: 5px 0 10px 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

And that should be all that you need. There might be some styling missing as my project has a lot of other css styling. So good luck everyone and I hope this helps!